# Trying to use a POS printer with Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, windows, printing

I have Epson TM-T20II connected over USB and RS232.

I can't seem to find an easy way to print to it from ruby using just the raw output. (USB001)

Currently the dev machine is Windows.
I can print using notepad without problems. I get no cut but that is fine for now. Also no non-ASCII chars support, but then again, it's just notepad.
I can't seem to find a way to find a device file for the printer for me to use in the script. Is ruby (windows) printing not a thing?

Is there an easy attempt to do this or do I need to use some other language, perhaps make a python receipt printing backend or so? Do I really need to do this from scratch, using trial and error (and a printer documentation)?

Thanks

Comment: You could set up an LPR port on Windows and use the `lpr` utility to send text documents to the printer? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731926.aspx

Comment: http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/GetArticle.aspx?docid=46cc343ea7304fb0b338d71ae8d3c94b_Setting_up_LPR_Printing_on_Windows_Windows_7.xml&pid=80

Comment: You can also use `ShellExecute`: http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.fi/2007/05/launching-apps-and-printing-docs-with.html ..and see more examples in Python here. These examples should be easy to convert to the Ruby equivalent: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python module for this at https://code.google.com/p/python-escpos/

I am not aware of any equivalent Ruby modules, but perhaps browsing the source code would be helpful.

Comment: I've tried ruby-escper, but the accented letters were like "p??li? ?lu?ou?k? k?? ?p?l ??belsk? ?dy"

Comment: I'll have a look at the rescues one. Seems promising. Also seems to support cutting OOB.